# Stata Menu & Icon Errors in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: icons, stata, menubar, root, ubuntu-13.10

I recently bought Stata 13.1 for my Ubuntu 13.10. And I noticed a few problems in it:

1) If I use Stata as a non-root or non-super user, then the menu bar of Stata will be on the top bar of Ubuntu desktop, and if you open a window from menu bar, the whole Stata will freeze and I have to force to quit. However, if I execute Stata as a root or superuser, this problem will be gone.

2) As before, there is no icon for Stata when it was installed. It seems like its default setting is to start Stata from terminal as a root/superuser, which is not too inconvenient but a little bit uncomfortable.

I looked up online and there is a blog talking about how to create an icon for it using some sort of bash-script, which works okay, but still couldn't solve the first problem.

I am guessing it's because Unity is not compatible with old x-window library and causes the first problem. Will switch to GNOME or KDE desktop help?

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. Specifically, in this case, you have a license and should go straight to Stata tech-support. Also, a reference to discussion "online" is needlessly vague: cite a URL please.

Comment: Perhaps migration to SuperUser or AskUbuntu could be an option for this question?

Comment: @radek In principle, possibly; in practice, why not go straight to the fountainhead?

Comment: @NickCox Hi Nick. The stream of communication between the fountainhead and the OP will probably remain personal. If we get the answer here - the collective hive mind of the new will be able to use it too.

Comment: @radek: LordOfLinux should see that request: O Lord, if you find out the answer, please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

WORKAROUND for Stata viewer help menus don't work when chosen from Global Menu:

The page below describes how to disable to global menu.  I applied the suggested fix and Stata 13.1 now runs correctly from the Application window.

http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/tips-and-tricks-ubuntu-after-installation-ubuntu-1204.htm

Disable or Enable the Global Menu
Ubuntu system places the application menu (File/Edit/View) (also known as AppMenu or Global Menu) on the top bar by default. If you want to disable this feature and move the menu back to the application's window, follow these steps:

Press Ctrl-Alt-T to run the Terminal.
Enter sudo su
Enter echo "export UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=0" > /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy
Log out and back in to the system.
To re-enable it, enter sudo rm /etc/X11/Xsession.d/81ubuntumenuproxy into the Terminal, then log out and back in the system.